# Retrieving a specific document version using SharePoint's Lists.GetListItems web service method

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Say I have three versions of the same document in a SharePoint 2010 site.  How would I retrieve the metadata for, say, the second version using web service?

I know that I can retrieve the latest version with the following SOAP request

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
        <listName>Shared Documents</listName>
        <viewName></viewName>
        <query>
            <Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FileRef"/>
            <Value Type="Text">https://mysite.com/sites/DocLib026/Shared Documents/_mytest5.doc</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
        </query>
        <rowLimit>200</rowLimit>
    </GetListItems>
</S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

How can I modify this so that I can retrieve any of the existing version?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sharepoint Object Model, once I have used the code found [here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/05/programmatically-get-versions-for-files-in-sharepoint-2010-document-library/):

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(“http://SharePointSite”))
{
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
 SPList docs = web.Lists["Mydocumentlib"];
  foreach (SPFile file in docs.RootFolder.Files)
 {
  Console.WriteLine(“File {0} has next version {1}. Version History:”, file.Url,           file.UIVersionLabel);
  foreach (SPFileVersion v in file.Versions.Cast().Reverse())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(” Version {0} checked in at {1} with this comment: ‘{2}’”,  v.VersionLabel, v.Created, v.CheckInComment);
  }
 }
}}
```

Just adjust the foreach method and do your magic stuff over there.

Comment: I need a web service solution.  I'm actually using Java to make SOAP web service call.  Thanks though.

Comment: Sorry for hear that, Duvo, let me take a look inside my server, may be we can figure out a way to display those items in a list view, and then caml-query to that view... do you have access to the list settings?

Comment: Yes, I was granted as site admin.  I though about CAML but didn't see any attribute that I can query against.  I've tried the _UIVersionString attribute, that only returns document with the matching version count at.  For example _UIVersionString=4.0 will return documents that has 4 versions.  Really appreciate the help